# Java HashMap not finding key, but it should

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a strange issue occuring in my application, I will quickly explain global architecture and then my problem in depth.

I use a service to populate a `HashMap<DomainObject,Boolean>` coming from my database (JPA driven) which is in turn returned to my view, via an EJB remote method call (using Apache Wicket). In this part, I add a new `DomainObject` to the map returned in order to store any new value from my end user.

The problem occurs when the user hit the "add" button in its browser, I try to retrieve the newly created item in my map, but it fails. By playing with the debugger I face the following things.

Assuming `HashMap<DomainObject, Boolean> map` and `DomainObject do` are the two variables interesting I have the following results in the debugger

`map.keySet();` gives me an object corresponding to `do` (even the @whatever simili-reference is identical), `hashcode()` on both objects returns similar value and `equals()` between the two returns `true`

`map.containsKey(do);` returns `false`

`map.get(do)`; returns `null`, weird because my key seems to be in the `map`.

Assuming my newly created item is the first key enumerated by `keySet()`, I do the following :
`map.get(new ArrayList(map.keySet()).get(0))`, and it returns null.

If it can help, by attaching breakpoints to my `DomainObject.equals()` and `DomainObject.hashcode()` methods I found that `map.get()` is only calling `hashcode()` and not `equals()`.

The only workaround I found is to recreate a new map on top of the existing one `new HashMap(map)`, in this new map, I have no problem at all looking up an object by its key.

I hope someone here can give my a pointer on what happens, thanks.

> Environment used :
>
> - Sun Java 1.6.0_26 x64 under OS X 10.7.1
> - OpenJDK 1.6.0_18 x64 under Debian 6.0.2 (2.6.32)
> - Apache Wicket 1.4.17
> - Oracle Glassfish 3.1.1
> - JBoss Hibernate 3.6.5

`DomainObject` code :

```
public class AssetComponentDetailTemplate extends BaseEntite<Long> {
public enum DataType {
    TXT,
    DATE,
    INT,
    JOIN,
    LIST,
    COULEURS,
    REFERENCE
}

public enum Tab {
    IDENTITE,
    LOCALISATION,
    CYCLE_DE_VIE,
    FINANCE,
    RESEAU,
    DETAIL
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;
@Column(nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private DataType dataType;
private Integer classNameId;
private Long orderId;
private Long nextAssetComponentDetailTemplateId;
private String unit;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Tab tab;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Long uniqueOrganizationId;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "idAssetComponentDetailTemplate", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private List<AssetComponentDetailJoin> assetComponentDetailJoins;

private Boolean mandatory = false;

public AssetComponentDetailTemplate() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(final Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public DataType getDataType() {
    return dataType;
}

public void setDataType(final DataType dataType) {
    this.dataType = dataType;
}

public Integer getClassNameId() {
    return classNameId;
}

public void setClassNameId(final Integer classNameId) {
    this.classNameId = classNameId;
}

public Long getUniqueOrganizationId() {
    return uniqueOrganizationId;
}

public void setUniqueOrganizationId(final Long uniqueOrganizationId) {
    this.uniqueOrganizationId = uniqueOrganizationId;
}

public Long getNextAssetComponentDetailTemplateId() {
    return nextAssetComponentDetailTemplateId;
}

public void setNextAssetComponentDetailTemplateId(final Long nextAssetComponentDetailTemplateId) {
    this.nextAssetComponentDetailTemplateId = nextAssetComponentDetailTemplateId;
}

public String getUnit() {
    return unit;
}

public void setUnit(final String unit) {
    this.unit = unit;
}

public Tab getTab() {
    return tab;
}

public void setTab(final Tab tab) {
    this.tab = tab;
}

public Long getOrder() {
    return orderId;
}

public void setOrder(final Long order) {
    this.orderId = order;
}

public Boolean isMandatory() {
    return mandatory;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    final AssetComponentDetailTemplate that = (AssetComponentDetailTemplate) o;

    if (classNameId != null ? !classNameId.equals(that.classNameId) : that.classNameId != null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (dataType != that.dataType) {
        return false;
    }
    if (id != null ? !id.equals(that.id) : that.id != null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (nextAssetComponentDetailTemplateId != null ?
        !nextAssetComponentDetailTemplateId.equals(that.nextAssetComponentDetailTemplateId) :
        that.nextAssetComponentDetailTemplateId != null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (orderId != null ? !orderId.equals(that.orderId) : that.orderId != null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (tab != that.tab) {
        return false;
    }
    if (uniqueOrganizationId != null ? !uniqueOrganizationId.equals(that.uniqueOrganizationId) :
        that.uniqueOrganizationId != null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (unit != null ? !unit.equals(that.unit) : that.unit != null) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (dataType != null ? dataType.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (classNameId != null ? classNameId.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (orderId != null ? orderId.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result +
             (nextAssetComponentDetailTemplateId != null ? nextAssetComponentDetailTemplateId.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (unit != null ? unit.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (tab != null ? tab.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (uniqueOrganizationId != null ? uniqueOrganizationId.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You should show some code. At least how you manage the map as well as the implementation of `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: Can we see some codes to look at?

Comment: I am afraid extracting the code won't be very easy (it is tightly coupled in the application). I add `DomainObject` code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This basically expands on Jesper's answer but the details may help you]

Since recreating the map using `new HashMap(map)` is able to find the element I am suspecting that the `hashCode()` of the DomainObject changed after adding it to the Map.

For example if your DomainObject looks the following

```
class DomainObject {
    public String name;
    long hashCode() { return name.hashCode(); }
    boolean equals(Object other) { /* compare name in the two */'
}
```

Then

```
   Map<DomainObject, Boolean> m = new HashMap<DomainObject, Boolean>();
   DomainObject do = new DomainObject(); 
   do.name = "ABC";
   m.put(do, true); // do goes in the map with hashCode of ABC
   do.name = "DEF";
   m.get(do);
```

The last statement above will return `null`. Because the `do` object you have inside the map is under the bucket of `"ABC".hashCode()`; there is nothing in the `"DEF".hashCode()` bucket.

**The hashCode of the Objects in map should not change once added to map. The best way to ensure it is that the fields on which hashCode depends must be immutable**.

Answer (score 4):

Is your `DomainObject` class immutable? Does it have properly implemented `hashCode` and `equals` methods?

Note that you will get into trouble if your `DomainObject` class is not immutable and you change the state of the object while it is in the map in a way that would change the result of calling `hashCode` or `equals`.

`hashCode` must be implemented in such a way that it returns the same value for two objects whenever `equals` returns true when comparing these objects. See the API documentation of `java.lang.Object.hashCode()` for detailed information.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your clue:

> hashcode() on both objects returns similar value

For the objects to be considered equal, their hash codes shouldn't just be similar, they must be identical.

If two objects have different hash codes, then as far as the container is concerned the objects are different. There's no need to even call `equals()`.

From the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29):

> The general contract of `hashCode` is:
>
> - If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then
>     calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce
>     the same integer result.

If I were you, I'd take a close look at `DomainObject.hashcode()` and `DomainObject.equals()` to see what's causing the contract to be broken.

Comment: When I mean identical, I mean equals value. The thing I found surprising is it works as expected from object coming from my Service layer but not with a view created one. This is a case widely used I think. If my `hashcode()` was wrong, new Map creation using the old one would not work either, am I right ?

Answer (score 1):

`map.get(do)` returning `null` could be easily explained by assuming that the `Boolean` value for that key might be `null` but `map.containsKey(do)` returning `false` would require `do`'s `hashCode` to be different at the time of calling `containsKey(do)` to it's `hashCode` at the time of retrieving it from the `keySet`.

To see what's happening, you could (temporarily) use a more verbose implementation of HashMap...
Maybe something like this:

```
public class VerboseHashMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

    private transient final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(VerboseHashMap.class);
    private HashMap<K, V> internalMap = new HashMap<K, V>();

    public boolean containsKey(Object o) {
        logger.debug("Object HashCode: " + o.hashCode());
        logger.debug("Map contents:");
        for (Entry<K, V> entry : internalMap.entrySet()) {
            logger.debug(entry.getKey().hashCode() + " - " + entry.getValue().toString());
        }
        return internalMap.containsKey(o);
    }

    public V get(Object key) {
        logger.debug("Object HashCode: " + key.hashCode());
        logger.debug("Map contents:");
        for (Entry<K, V> entry : internalMap.entrySet()) {
             logger.debug(entry.getKey().hashCode() + " - " + entry.getValue().toString());
        }
        return internalMap.get(key);
    }

}
```

You'd need to map all the other requirements of the Map interface to your internalMap as well.

Note: This code is not intended for production, nor is it in any way performance oriented, nice or unsmelly....

2nd note (after seeing your code): To use your domain-object as a key for your hashMap, you should only use the immutable parts of your object for hashCode and equals (in this case the id-value). Else lazy-loading further values would change the hashCode...

In Response to your comment:

```
public class Demo extends TestCase {

public void testMap() {

    Map<DomainObject, String> map = new HashMap<DomainObject, String>();
    DomainObject sb = new DomainObject();
    map.put(sb, "Some value");
    System.out.println(map.containsKey(sb));
    sb.value = "Some Text";
    System.out.println(map.containsKey(sb));

}

    private static class DomainObject {

        public String value = null;

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((value == null) ? 0 : value.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            DomainObject other = (DomainObject) obj;
            if (value == null) {
                if (other.value != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!value.equals(other.value))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

prints

```
true 
false
```

The HashCode for the key is computed at the time of putting it into the map.

Comment: If I compute `hashCode()` on my `do` and on the key corresponding to `do` at the same time I get exactly the same result, so I would say it is not a changed element in my `do` object (as it references the same object). Right-hand values in my map are either `true` or `false`, never `null` and the debugger shows the value is `false` in my case.

Comment: Thanks, I now understand what's going on