# How does a hashmap saves and looks up for a key

Tags: java, hashmap

I encountered a problem about `HashMap`. After some debugging with no result, I wrote a short piece of code to test the `HashMap`. But the result turns out more confusing!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point a = new Point(0, 0);          // java.awt.Point
    Map<Point, Integer> map = new HashMap<Point, Integer>();
    map.put(a, 0);
    System.out.println(map.containsKey(new Point(0, 0)));    // true
    a.x = 1;
    System.out.println(map.containsKey(new Point(0, 0)));    // false
    System.out.println(map.containsKey(new Point(1, 0)));    // false
    System.out.println(map.containsKey(a));                  // false
}
```

I was expecting the 2nd or 3rd output could give me a true, and the 4th definitely true. But the fact seems not consent.

---

About my intent to change the key, I used the map to save some mobs. The mob has Point field, and the key of the map uses the same reference. Then I might be able to look for the mob by its coordination and also changes the coordination easily.

Comment: What is `Point`? Does it have an appropriate `hashCode()` and `equals()` implementation?

Comment: Also, never modify an element which you use as a key in a `Map`.

Comment: `Point` have to override `hashCode()` and `equals()`. The `HashMap` takes the value of `Point.hashCode()` as the key value

Comment: @drkunibar doesnt' the 1st true indicates that the methods have already been overrode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java HashMap not finding key, but it should](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565341/java-hashmap-not-finding-key-but-it-should)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look it up in the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java) and understand it, although not so easily as I thought.

The problem is that when you change the value of `x` you make the object within the hash tree seem to be at the wrong position, I'll illustrate it.

You place the key inside a tree that looks like this:

```
.../-- Point(0,0)
root
---\.. nothing
```

If you had put Point(1,0) inside it it would look like this:

```
.../.. nothing
root
...\.. Point(1,0)
```

So when you altered the key the tree looks like this:

```
.../.. Point(1,0)
root
...\.. nothing
```

Now you look for `Point(1,0)` and the map traverses the lower branch where such a key should belong, but there is nothing. And when you look for `Point(0,0)` it traverses the upper branch where there is the wrong key.

Therefore it is important to NEVER change a value thats part of the `.hashCode()` of an object. Instead use a new instance of that object to do alternations or use a clone of the Object to place inside the `HashMap`.

Alternatively if you want to change the keys you can remove it from the map, alter it and put it back in. Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point a = new Point(0, 0);          // java.awt.Point
    Map<Point, Integer> map = new HashMap<Point, Integer>();
    map.put(a, 0);
    System.out.println(map.containsKey(new Point(0, 0)));    // true
    Integer value = map.remove(a);
    a.x = 1;
    map.put(a,value);
    System.out.println(map.containsKey(new Point(0, 0)));    // false
    System.out.println(map.containsKey(new Point(1, 0)));    // true
    System.out.println(map.containsKey(a));                  // true
}
```

You may want to shift the remove, alter and put method to an own method inside the object to have it available. You can call it `setAndRelocate(int newX, int newY, Map container)` and have it back to one line in your regular code.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you're getting is normal due albeit confusing due to how HashMap is implemented.

Roughly, here how putting a value V with a key K works:

- HashMap computes the hashcode H of the key K
- H is used as an index (trimming it if necessary) in an array where the values are stored: `data[H] = Entry(K, V)`

Afterwards, when you call `get(K)` or `containsKey(K)`:

- HashMap computes the hashcode H of the key
- It then checks if `data[H]` is not null and that it's key **equals** the key you provided
- If so, it returns the value V for `get` or true for `containsKey`

In you case, you called `put` with Point(0, 0). Let's say `Point(0, 0).hashcode()` returned 0. So the value gets stored in index 0:

```
data = [Point(0, 0), null, ...]
```

You then modify the point (`a.x=1`). The key is modified but HashMap can't detect it and so it won't move the entry to the correct index.

```
data = [Point(1, 0), null, ...]
```

Afterwards, `map.containsKey(new Point(0, 0))` returns false because according to how `containsKey` works as shown above:

- hashcode returns 0 (same as when you originally put it)
- But then, `Point(0, 0)` (the key you're testing) is not equal to `Point(1, 0)` (the key you stored), hence the false

The third test also prints false because `hashcode(Point(1, 0))` (the key you're testing) might and does return a different value from `hashcode(Point(0, 0))` (the key you stored). Let's say it returns 1, whereas the initial point is stored at index 0. That's why it also returns false.

Morale of the story: **The keys used in a HashMap must be immutable or weird behavior would ensue**.